# How to add a product to it?

Tags: magento

```
   <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
```

the code is form cart.phtml if i want to add a product into `$this->getItems()` which from a specified category then output it? how do i do? thank you

i should know what information of the product, then i can put it into $this->getItems() then loop out the information?

Comment: magento has tech support, no?  it's a commercial product.

Comment: Do some Google you will get the answer.

Comment: i did it before, but don't get any useful thing, thank you

Comment: i should know what information of the product, then i can put it into $this->getItems() then loop out the information?

Answer (score 1):

The way to accomplish this would be to add the item to your cart using either method below.

1. Adding a Product to the Cart via Querystring [read more](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring)

   > /path/to/app/checkout/cart/add?product=[id]&qty=[qty]
2. Add product to cart programmatically ([read more](http://gzchauhan.blogspot.com/2012/03/programmatically-add-product-in-cart-in.html))

`

```
$params = array(
    'product' => 23,
    'qty' => 2,
);
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->load(23); // load product id 23
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save(); 
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

`